# To Do - List Item gets added twice

Tags: javascript

If you don't enter a to do you get an alert saying so, but when closing it off it renders out a duplicate to do.

Not sure why, could someone explain why?

Cheers

https://jsfiddle.net/1usque27/

HTML

```
<input id="add-to-do" type="text" placeholder="Add to do">
<button id="add-to-do-btn" type="button" name="button">Add</button>
<div id="main"></div>
```

JS

// To do

```
var toDo = {
  toDos: [],
  init: function() {
    this.cacheDom();
    this.bindEvents();
  },
  cacheDom: function() {
    this.main = document.getElementById('main');
    this.addBtn = document.getElementById('add-to-do-btn');
    this.toDoValue = document.getElementById('add-to-do')
  },
  bindEvents: function() {
    this.addBtn.addEventListener("click", this.addToDo.bind(this));
  },
  render: function() {
    for(i=0; i<this.toDos.length; i++) {
      var toDoList = document.createElement("li");
      var toDoListText = document.createTextNode(this.toDos[i]);
      toDoList.appendChild(toDoListText);
    }
    this.main.appendChild(toDoList);
  },
  addToDo: function() {
    var toDoValue = this.toDoValue.value;
    if(toDoValue) {
      this.toDos.push(this.toDoValue.value);
    }
    else {
      alert("add to do!");
    }
    this.toDoValue.value = '';
    this.render();
  }
}

toDo.init();
```

Answer (score 4):

Because the function continues with the rest of the code after the alert. You need to stop the execution by returning false:

```
else {
  alert("add to do!");
  return false;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/1usque27/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

I did in this way https://jsfiddle.net/t0axtoub/
I just replaced `this.toDoValue.value = ''; this.render();` into `if`. It works right.

Since we don't have any changes we don't need any `render`

Answer (score 0):

The "real" problem is with your `render` method. It always renders only the last item. You could check this effect by manually calling `render` multiple times. [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/1usque27/2/). You were redefining `toDoList` inside loop and only the last one were appended to `this.main` . If you need to rerender the whole list you could do it this way

```
function() {
    var toDoList, toDoListText;
    this.main.innerHTML = '' // clean previous render
    for(var i=0; i<this.toDos.length; i++) {
      toDoList = document.createElement("li");
      toDoListText = document.createTextNode(this.toDos[i]);
      toDoList.appendChild(toDoListText);
      this.main.appendChild(toDoList);
    }

  }
```

```js
// To do

var toDo = {
  toDos: [],
  init: function() {
    this.cacheDom();
    this.bindEvents();
  },
  cacheDom: function() {
    this.main = document.getElementById('main');
    this.addBtn = document.getElementById('add-to-do-btn');
    this.toDoValue = document.getElementById('add-to-do')
  },
  bindEvents: function() {
    this.addBtn.addEventListener("click", this.addToDo.bind(this));
  },
  render: function() {
    this.main.innerHTML = ''
    for(i=0; i<this.toDos.length; i++) {
      var toDoList = document.createElement("li");
      var toDoListText = document.createTextNode(this.toDos[i]);
      toDoList.appendChild(toDoListText);
      this.main.appendChild(toDoList);
    }
    
  },
  addToDo: function() {
    var toDoValue = this.toDoValue.value;
    if(toDoValue) {
      this.toDos.push(this.toDoValue.value);
    }
    else {
      alert("add to do!");
    }
    this.toDoValue.value = '';
    this.render();
  }
}

toDo.init();
```

```html
<input id="add-to-do" type="text" placeholder="Add to do">
<button id="add-to-do-btn" type="button" name="button">Add</button>
<div id="main"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just insert the render inside the if(todoValue){
}

```
  addToDo: function() {
    var toDoValue = this.toDoValue.value;
    if (toDoValue) {
      this.toDos.push(this.toDoValue.value);
      this.render();
    } else {
      alert("add to do!");
    }
    this.toDoValue.value = '';

  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1usque27/7/